# Add attachements to send mail in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am fairly new to Yii. I am using YiiMail extension to send mails. I am able to send mails but unable to send attachments with it.

I have got the following code but now knowing what that "tempName" would exactly mean?

mycontroller-

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('filename'); // get the CUploadedFile
$uploadedFileName = $uploadedFile->tempName; // will be something like 'myfile.jpg'
$swiftAttachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($uploadedFile); // create a Swift Attachment
$this->email->attach($swiftAttachment); // now attach the correct type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if you upload a file (e.g. `c:\path\file\myfile.jpg` ), if is temporary stored on the server in a temporarry folder with a temporary name (e.g. `/tmp/zxhjkqwf.tmp` ).
The CUploadedFile wraps all the functions you need to access and manipulate the file.
So the `tempname` will be the path to your file on the server.
I guess you should try to alter your code lioke this:

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('filename'); // get the CUploadedFile
$uploadedFileName = $uploadedFile->tempName; // will be something like 'myfile.jpg'
$swiftAttachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($uploadedFileName); // create a Swift Attachment from the temporary file
$this->email->attach($swiftAttachment); // now attach the correct type
```

See more info in the [Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#tempName-detail)

Comment: Okay thanks! But it gives me an error as "Trying to get property of non-object" which points to the second line in the above code.

Comment: So that means probably that there was no file uploaded, so you should check if the upload went correctly

Comment: Its the same code that I have written above, I dont understand where I am going wrong

Comment: if it worked before is will work also now, because I changed only the 3rd line. So you have to recheck the upload, if you are really uploading something. Maybe try a `var_dump` of the `$uploadedFile`.
Maybe you renamed the `input` field in the upload form or you have some other error while uploading